# How to input a 1 x n matrix (row x column format) from a text file in java program using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, file-handling

PS: all integers in the file are more than one digit.

I want to input a 1 x n matrix from a text file in a java program. I can input a matrix with single digit numbers by the following code, suggest solutions that would modify the same.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


class New_data{
public int[][] allocation= new int[25][25];
public int[][] need= new int[25][25];
public int[][] max= new int[25][25];
public int[] available=new int[25]; 
public int rows=0,col=0;
int count_flag=0;

void input_avaliable()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the available matrix\nDimensions: " + col+":1");
}

void readfile(String s,int arr[][]) throws IOException
{
    File file= new File(s);
    FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(isr); 

    String line;
    int i=0,j=0;

    int shift=0;        //shift int is used to convert char array to int

    char[] ch=new char [50];

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(count_flag==0)
        {
        rows++;
        col=(line.length());
        col=col/2;
        }
        else{}

        ch=line.toCharArray();
        shift=0;


        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            arr[rows-1][j]=ch[j+shift];
            shift++;
        }
    }
    count_flag=1;



    br.close();
}   

void need() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=col;j++)
        {
            need[i][j]=max[i][j]-allocation[i][j];
        }
    }
}

}

class Bankers{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    New_data Data=new New_data();

    String location=new String("allocation.txt");
    Data.readfile(location,Data.allocation); 

    location="max.txt";
    Data.readfile(location,Data.max);

    Data.need();
}

}
```

This code outputs two arrays properly, but fails when the input file do not have single digit integers.

Comment: Why not split the string (`line`) using whatever separator you have between your numbers?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson   I keep getting errors like this: "[Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302" whenever I use the spllit function.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error, more like you are printing an array or similar

Comment: Yes, it isn't an error, it's prinitng something. But what the heck is it prinitng!!!

Comment: Then why are you saying it is an error? You are probably printing some type of object that doesn't have `toString()` implemented, like an array. Update the code in your question so it matches what you have now